# IPython Javascript client API

Tags: ipython, jupyter

Does IPython provide a Javascript client API for interfacing to a kernel server?

I had a look at https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/development/messaging.html which explains the wire protocol between a front-end and a kernel.

I would be interested in finding out how the current web client communicates with a kernel and in particular how I could leverage JavaScript in order to programmatically create new notebooks from my own custom web client

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See https://gist.github.com/disarticulate/d06069ff3e71cf828e5329beab8cb084

There you can see a nice example:

```
// a very basic output handling
var handle_output = function (data) {console.log(data);}

//callbacks is an object whose so special, it appears to only have been documented in
//the source code, as no only google found me a link.
//callbacks.iopub.output is used to get the data from execute
var callbacks = {
        iopub : {
             output : handle_output,
    }
}

//execute anything you want; if a string value is returned
//you can print it out and pass it to the callbacks 
//(or do other things, no idea, it's poorly documented online 
//(read the source F12->static/notebook/js/services/kernels/kernel.js)
//kernel.js/Kernel.prototype.execute 
var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
kernel.execute("print(json.dumps(python_dict))",callbacks)
```

You can see the definition going to in /static/services/kernels/kernel.js